# Can I have multiple outputs in an OpenShift Origin build?

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm building several base images for our infrastructure and would like to mimic the Docker Hub nomenclature for the image tags. For example, [Java image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) includes several aliases for the same image, e.g. `8` and `latest` is the same image.

If I were to replicate this system in `ImageStream`s, I would need to create a `BuildConfig` with an output specification like this:

```
"output": {
  "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "jdk:8"
  }
}
```

Obviously, this only includes one tag, so even if I were to write

```
"output": {
  "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "jdk:8"
  },
  "to": {
    "kind": "ImageStreamTag"
    "name": "jdk:latest"
  }
}
```

only the latest definition would actually be executed.

Is there any proper way to push the same image into different tags apart from creating a different `BuildConfig` (which would probably "build" from Docker image to Docker image)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a card on the trello board to do this: https://trello.com/c/nOX8FTRq/686-5-support-multiple-tags-for-a-build-output .

You should also be able to do this using `oc tag` to avoid having to run the same build twice.

Comment: It has been suggested [in a comment posted as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900264/5211833) that this link is now dead.